# Join Date and Time to DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I am retrieving data from an iSeries where there is a separate date and time fields. I want to join them into a DateTime field in my C# project. I don't see a way to add just a time to a DateTime field. How would you suggest accomplishing this?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

How are they being stored? Assuming that the date portion is being stored as a `DateTime` of midnight of the day in question and the time is a `TimeSpan`, you can just add them.

```
DateTime date = ...;
TimeSpan time = ...;

DateTime result = date + time;
```

Comment: I think this one will work the best for me in this case. Thanks!

Comment: this will only work if date variable has time part 00:00:00 otherwise time variable will be added on top of date and it will be unexpected result.

Comment: @batmaci Yes, that is specifically stated in the answer.

Answer (score 146):

You can do this quite easily:

```
DateTime dateOnly;
DateTime timeOnly;
...
DateTime combined = dateOnly.Date.Add(timeOnly.TimeOfDay);
```

`TimeOfDay` returns a `TimeSpan`, which you then add to the date.

Edit (thanks to commenters below) - to be safe, use `dateOnly.Date` to ensure the date part only.

Comment: A word of caution to the viewer here that you must make sure that `DateTime dateOnly` does only contain a date otherwise, with a big enough TimeSpan, when you preform the `Add`, you will increase the day by 1!

Comment: @CodeBlend is correct, this happened to me.  The best way to cover yourself is to do: `DateTime combined = dateOnly.Date.Add(timeOnly.TimeOfDay);`

Comment: Good catch, @RodolfoDeLosSantos! I sent a request to update the solution to match your suggestion.

Comment: Slightly different example: to combine today's date with a TimeOnly time: DateTime combined = DateTime.Today.Add(timeOnly.ToTimeSpan());

Comment: Yet another example, to combine a DateOnly with a TimeOnly: DateTime combined = dateOnly.ToDateTime(timeOnly)

Answer (score 8):

You could easily construct a [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) from your "time" field.

Once you have that, just do:

```
TimeSpan time = GetTimeFieldData();
dateField = dateField.Add(time);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Datetime date = new DateTime(Date1.Year, Date1.Month, Date1.Day, Time1.Hour, Time1.Minute, Time1.Second);
```

Comment: using `Time1.Second`, you are loosing precision, eg. Time1 = TimeSpan.FromMillisecond(0.5);

Answer (score 5):

My answer addresses joining two objects of `DateOnly` and `TimeOnly` in .NET 6:

```
DateOnly orderDate = ...
TimeOnly orderTime = ...
DateTime orderDateTime = orderDate.ToDateTime(orderTime);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `TimeSpan` to a `DateTime` and write something like this.

```
// inside consuming function
ISeriesObject obj = getMyObject();
DateTime dt = getDate(obj) + getTime(obj);

private DateTime getDate(ISeriesObject obj)
{
     //return a DateTime
}


private TimeSpan getTime(ISeriesObject obj)
{
     //return a TimeSpan
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
var output = date.Date + time.TimeOfDay;
```

or

```
var output = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day,
                          time.Hour, time.Minute, time.Second);
```

suppose that both variable `date` and `time` are both of Type `DateTime`

Comment: Using `time.Second` you missing the case where `time = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0.5)`

Comment: @malat there is a comment about `date` and `time` are both of type `DateTime`

Comment: `var output = date.Date + time.TimeOfDay;` is the right answer. Using the constructor (your snd solution) will fail with the example I gave for `time`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that adding the time to the date is not your biggest problem here. As @Reed Copsey mentioned, you just create a DateTime from the date and then `.Add` the time.

However, you need to make sure that the iSeries date and time (a Unix time most probably) are in the same representation as the .Net representation. Thus, you most probably need to convert it by adding it to a Jan 1, 1970 DateTime as well.

Answer (score 0):

**.NET 8 Update**

As the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/how-to-use-dateonly-timeonly#work-with-timespan-and-datetime) suggests:

```
var theTime = new TimeOnly(11, 25, 46);   // 11:25 AM and 46 seconds
var theDate = new DateOnly(2015, 10, 21); // October 21, 2015
var theDateTime = theDate.ToDateTime(theTime);
var reverseTime = TimeOnly.FromDateTime(theDateTime);

Console.WriteLine($"Date only is {theDate}");
Console.WriteLine($"Time only is {theTime}");
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine($"Combined to a DateTime type, the value is {theDateTime}");
Console.WriteLine($"Converted back from DateTime, the time is {reverseTime}");

/* This example produces the following output:
 * 
 * Date only is 10/21/2015
 * Time only is 11:25 AM
 * 
 * Combined to a DateTime type, the value is 10/21/2015 11:25:46 AM
 * Converted back from DateTime, the time is 11:25 AM
*/
```

Answer (score -3):

Cant you simply format the date part and time part as separate strings, then join them together? Then you can parse the string back to a DateTime object