# Combine two datetime variables into one (up to seconds precision)

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a little problem that I just cannot seem to solve.  I have two datetime variables, the important data in the one is the year, month and day.  The other datetime variable stores the hour, minute and second.

The reason for this chaos is due to the database where I'm pulling the data from, where they have two different columns to store the actual date and the time.  Here is the code:

```
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(dTable.Rows[i][0]);
DateTime time = Convert.ToDateTime(dTable.Rows[i][1]);

DateTime newDateTime = new DateTime();
```

The newDateTime need to have the complete datetime set, where the date fraction is in the date variable and the time fraction is in the time variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Join Date and Time to DateTime in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142547/join-date-and-time-to-datetime-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This should do:

```
newDateTime = date.Date + time.TimeOfDay;
```

Comment: this is the correct answer to preserve milliseconds precision.

Answer (score 10):

Using [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/272ba130.aspx):

```
DateTime newDateTime = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, 
                                    time.Hour, time.Minute, time.Second);
```

Comment: You are loosing Milliseconds precision, eg. `time = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0.5)`

Comment: @malat The OP specified "The other datetime variable stores the hour, minute and second." so nothing is lost.

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTime newDateTime = date.Date.Add(time.Time);
```

The `Date` property excludes any time component (effectively midnight of the specified date), and the `Time` property returns just the time component as a `TimeSpan`.

Here we take the date portion of the `date` variable to get midnight, and add to it the time component of the `time` variable, to get the correct date and time.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this below

```
    TimeSpan timeSpan = time.TimeOfDay;
        string s = string.Format("{0} {1}", date.Date.ToString("MM dd yyyy"), time.ToString());
        DateTime combinedDateTime = DateTime.Parse(s);
```