# SQL / Linq Join two tables and join date and time into single query

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have two tables shown below.  SessionBooking.Date is a Date field and TimeSlot.StartTime is a Time field.

Table Schema:

[image]

You can see the current query below i am joining the two tables successfully however i need to join the date and the starttime into a single "Datetime" field so that i can sort by datetime (current date and time)

How can I do this and also how can this be written in Linq to SQL.

I have this so far (excluding join)

```
List<SessionBooking> bookings = db.SessionBookings.Where(m => m.MemberId == this.Id && m.LocationId == this.HomeLocationId && m.Date >= currentDate).OrderByDescending(m => m.Date).ThenBy(m => m.TimeSlot.StartTime).Take(limit).ToList();
```

[image]

Comment: I feel your system has a bad design. Conceptually, date and time should always be stored together. Your notion of "timeslots" shouldn't be in your database at all, instead that should be handled by your business-logic layer.

Comment: What's wrong with ordering by date and time as you already do?

Comment: You can simply add date and time to create a datetime variable. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142547/join-date-and-time-to-datetime-in-c-sharp.

Comment: Also, always prefer explicit `JOIN` syntax to `FROM x, y` syntax.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this   `SELECT a.Date + b.time`

FROM [eMart].[dbo].sessionBooking as a
      `join Timeslot as b on a.id = b.id`

Comment: You can't do this just like that. Moreover, the question is how to do it in LINQ. Please try to improve your answer.